# Does anyone knows a 'Leo' surname transliterated from the 劉/刘 characters?

Tags: simplified-characters, traditional-characters, mainland-china, surnames

Grandfather from Macau, China came to the Philippines when he was only 13 years old. His name in my Dad's birth certificate is 'Leo Suening'.

yDNA (paternal test) results points me to the Liu/劉/刘 surname. Leo sounds Liu too.

Answer (score 3):

The Wikipedia page for [Liu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liu#:%7E:text=%E5%8A%89%20%2F%20%E5%88%98%20(%2Fljo%CA%8A,Liw)%20is%20a%20Chinese%20surname.) says:

> 劉 / 刘 (/ljoʊ/ or /ljuː/;[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liu#:%7E:text=%E5%8A%89%20%2F%20%E5%88%98%20(%2Fljo%CA%8A,Liw)%20is%20a%20Chinese%20surname.) romanised as Liu, Lau, Leo, Ryu, Yoo, Lew, Lieu, Liou, Liw) is a Chinese surname. Liu as transcribed in English can represent several different surnames written in different Chinese characters.

As you can see the surname has been Romanized in many different ways, including: Leo. So, 刘 would be the simplified character writing for Leo while 劉 would be the traditional character writing for Leo.

Comment: Foreigners tend to use words in their own language to remember names.  Philippines are Spanish influenced, hence Leo is simple and easy to memorized.  Likewise, many Chinese like to use Mandarin to memorize English vocabulary: 一颗糯米 for economy.

Comment: thank you a lot @JamesLiu刘老师